# Rewrite wordpress subfolder just admin to use SSL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

We have a wordpress install in the location `/blog/` and are trying to redirect HTTPS user to none HTTP unless they're using the admin files in `/blog/wp-admin/`

So far I have the following rewrite but it's not allowing HTTPS for `/blog/wp-admin/`, where am I going wrong?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^wp-admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

RewriteBase is used only on RewriteRule, not in REQUEST_URI.

Use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*wp-admin
```